# WM_INITMENU has unexpected wParam for system menu

Tags: winapi

Message WM_INITMENU is supposed to contain menu handle in wParam. For some reason, for system menu, wParam is something different. Sometimes it is even negative number. However, it is always the same within the same instance.

I can ignore wParam and use the handle, returned by GetSystemMenu, to modify menu items - all works. I don't have other menus and can skip the check, but it is doesn't look accurate.

This is simple desktop C++ non-MFC project on Windows 10 21h1. I have a few other messages and all of them have expected wParam, so it must be "by design". [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-initmenu) did not tell anything special. Maybe somebody knows, what is the value in wParam?

Thanks--

Comment: How did you determine, that the `wParam` value were invalid? Being different from the value returned by `GetSystemMenu` doesn't make it invalid.

Comment: "Programming Windows" by Charles Petzoid say this about `WM_INITMENU`: "*The value of `wParam` is the handle to your main menu **even if the user is selecting an item from the system menu**.*" So I would just stick with using `GetSystemMenu()`, if that is the actual menu you intend to modify. Plus, it makes your code's intention clearer. Maybe someday you decide to add another menu to your program, then you wouldn't have to differentiate which menu `wParam` is pointing at.

Comment: @IInspectable: you are correct, just tried to use contents of wParam instead of the value from GetSystemMenu, and it worked. This is weird: the handle sometimes is 0xFFFFFFFFnnnnnnnn and sometimes 0x000000000000nnn. Probably higher word is populated from the most significant bit of 32-bit part, but sometimes the value is pretty small. I still see no relation to GetSystemMenu, but you answered the question. Thanks!